# Ordinal Numbers With PHP

Tags: php, numbers, ordinal

I need to make output like this above, but how to add numbers , i can do with < ol > but its not what i need, < ol > tag give me different order.. any idea how to make this and add number before links?

```
1. Site.com      6. Site.com
2. Site.com      7. Site.com
3. Site.com      8. Site.com
4. Site.com      9. Site.com
5. Site.com     10. Site.com
```

Here is php code

```
<?
$list = $my_db->fetch("SELECT " . MY_PREFIX . "list.id, name,address, in_hits, out_hits FROM " . MY_PREFIX . "list LEFT JOIN " . MY_PREFIX . "sites ON " . MY_PREFIX . "list.id=" . MY_PREFIX . "sites.id WHERE status >0 AND status <3 ORDER BY in_hits DESC LIMIT 9");

$count = 1;

echo "<ul>";
foreach($list as $site) {;?>
<li><a href="<?php echo "/out.php?url=" . $site["address"];?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));?>"><?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));?></a></li>

<?
if ($count == 5) {echo "</ul><ul>";}
$count++;
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Tell me what should happen if you will have more than 10 records in table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `start` attribute

```
<ol start="6">
    <li>anything</li>
</ol>
```

or you can use css (*multiple column* property) applied on one ordered list

Answer (score 1):

How about use some counter:

```
<?
$list = $my_db->fetch("SELECT " . MY_PREFIX . "list.id, name,address, in_hits, out_hits FROM " . MY_PREFIX . "list LEFT JOIN " . MY_PREFIX . "sites ON " . MY_PREFIX . "list.id=" . MY_PREFIX . "sites.id WHERE status >0 AND status <3 ORDER BY in_hits DESC LIMIT 9");

$count = 1;
echo "<ul>";
foreach($list as $site) {;?>
<li><a href="<?php echo "/out.php?url=" . $site["address"];?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));?>"><?php echo $count ?>. <?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));?></a></li>

<?
if ($count % 5 == 0) {echo "</ul><ul>";}
$count++;
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

And I also changed the line `if ($count == 5)` to `if ($count % 5 == 0)`. So every 5th row will start new list.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
foreach($list as $site) {;?>
<li><a href="<?php echo "/out.php?url=" . $site["address"];?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));?>">

    <?php
    $i=1;
    $j=6
    if(count<=5){
    echo .$i.'.'.htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));$i++;

    }else{
    echo .$j.'.'.htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));$j++;
    }
    ?>
    </a></li>
```

rest code remains same

Comment: This will produce same numbers in same columns.

Comment: my bad, forgot the increment

Comment: why you did't add the operator `++` in the code like this? `echo ($i++) . '. ' . htmlentities(stripslashes($site["name"]));`.

Comment: does the same, let me admit, you approach looks great to me, I am doing quite conventional

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to show some fetaures, that language gives you.